# How would you go about detecting events defined by libraries in other classes?

Tags: c#, sdl

So I'm working with SdlDotNet - which basically converts SDL calls into what C# should look like and I ran into an issue.

That issue being that because the SdlDotNet is running in a different class to the main part of my application - I can't detect when it's closing.

The SdlDotNet library has an event that fires when it is told to close, and that event is:

```
SdlDotNet.Core.Events.Quit
```

In the object viewer - the event is shown as such:

```
public static event System.EventHandler<QuitEventArgs> Quit
Member of SdlDotNet.Core.Events
```

What I've done, is there is a main Windows form application that calls upon the SDL class like so:

```
private void drawToScreen()
{
    //Starts the SDL off drawing to the screen
    SDLDraw sdl = new SDLDraw();
    sdl.startDrawing();

    //How would I go about detecting SdlDotNet.Events.Quit
    //From the class I've instanced

    //When I was on my original Windows Forms implementation
    //It worked like this:

    ////sdl.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(detectClose);

    //But just copying that structure and trying

    ////sdl.Events.Quit += new QuitArgs(detectClose);

    //Doesn't have the same effect, because sdl does not contain a definition for 'Events'
}
private void detectClose(object sender, QuitArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("SDL closed!")
}
```

So, I guess the question is how do I listen for Events.Quit firing in the class I called from the class I called it from?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did not work ? What was the effect of sdl.Events.Quit += new QuitArgs(detectClose); ?

Comment: It tells me that 'sdl' does not contain a definition for 'Events'.

Comment: As is explained below, this is because the event is static, and is associated with its class, not with its instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration reveals that this is a static event, therefore it is associated with the class, not an instance.  Use

```
SdlDotNet.Core.Events.Quit += new QuitArgs(detectClose);
```

Comment: This man is right, I made a stupid as hell mistake and didn't read the documentation.